# Using a for loop to add coordinates to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use a for loop to add a column that has longitude and latitude coordinates based. The code that I have is stated:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder',timeout=None)
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode)

for x in pop['CityState']:
    pull = pd.DataFrame(geolocator.geocode(pop.iloc[0][11]))
    push = pull.loc[1]
    pop['Coordinates'] = push
```

The error I'm getting is

```
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 131, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1607, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1614, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
```

The dataframe is

```
                       City          State  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017  2018                                      CityState
0                         Semmes city        Alabama  4168  4183  4208  4377  4492  4686  4886  5087  5254                           Semmes city, Alabama
4                       Edna Bay city         Alaska    42    43    43    43    43    44    44    43    42                          Edna Bay city, Alaska
5                       Kachemak city         Alaska   477   482   486   487   489   491   493   492   490                          Kachemak city, Alaska
6                      Utqiagvik city         Alaska  4243  4285  4375  4443  4434  4447  4399  4463  4488                         Utqiagvik city, Alaska
7                     Whale Pass city         Alaska    31    32    32    32    33    32    32    32    31                        Whale Pass city, Alaska
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show the dataframe

Comment: Why the loop? You start it, but never use `x`.

Comment: I'm new to Python so forgive the ignorance, but the intended purpose of the loop is to add the coordinates to each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim    
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

pop=pd.DataFrame({'CityState':['Semmes city, Alabama',
'Edna Bay city, Alaska',
'Kachemak city, Alaska',
'Utqiagvik city, Alaska',
'Whale Pass city, Alaska']})

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder',timeout=None)
geocode = RateLimiter(geolocator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)

pop['location'] = pop['CityState'].apply(geocode)
pop['Coordinates'] = pop['location'].apply(lambda loc: tuple(loc.point) if loc else None)
pop.drop('location',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

---

```
                 CityState                                     Coordinates
0     Semmes city, Alabama           (30.7508005, -88.23437043506506, 0.0)
1    Edna Bay city, Alaska           (55.971902, -133.68282049513726, 0.0)
2    Kachemak city, Alaska          (59.6731384, -151.43537315231583, 0.0)
3   Utqiagvik city, Alaska                 (71.2905556, -156.7886112, 0.0)
4  Whale Pass city, Alaska  (56.114206499999995, -133.18951281550073, 0.0)
```

Comment: I tried that, and got this error: geopy.exc.GeocoderQuotaExceeded: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
RateLimiter caught an error, retrying (1/2 tries). Called with (*('Lowndes County, Georgia',), **{}).

Comment: @wickedflow "A large number of DataFrame rows might produce a significant amount of geocoding requests to a Geocoding service, which might be throttled by the service (e.g. by returning Too Many Requests 429 HTTP error or timing out)." [source](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.16.0/#usage-with-pandas)

Comment: it's a dataframe of 30000 rows, is it too much for Geocoder to handle?

Comment: @wickedflow simply, yes. but check the link. there is a wrapper which can solve this problem

Comment: @wickedflow I edited my answer. like this it should work but takes 8+ hrs